# Does AtomicU64 always undergo operations as big endian in rust?

Tags: rust, atomic

So I am doing some experiments involving wait-free or lock-free reference counting, and I was trying to combine the storage of a small bit flag set and an atomic counter. I have come up with the following code:

```
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicU64, Ordering};

fn main() {
   let num = AtomicU64::new((3 as u64) << 62);
   println!("{:#b}", num.load(Ordering::SeqCst));
   num.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
   println!("{:#b}", num.load(Ordering::SeqCst));
   assert_eq!((num.load(Ordering::SeqCst) & !((3 as u64) << 62)), 1 as u64);
}
```

Which prints

```
0b1100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0b1100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

and does not fail the `assert_eq`. However, I am wondering if this code will work cross platform? Does `AtomicU64` always undergo operations as big endian ? Or does it sometime under go operations as little endian ? If so, how should I change my code to work on any platform that `AtomicU64` works on ?

For reference, this result is obtained from the rust playground.

Comment: Where do you believe you depend on endianess in your code?

Comment: Basically, i need the little flag i store in the integer to always be at the opposite end of where addition takes places. Like `store(0b11 << 62)` and `fetch_add(1)` should never be on the same side of the integer

Comment: That isn't endianness, it's simple arithmetic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does AtomicU64 always undergo operations as big endian in rust?

Depends on the platform.

> I am wondering if this code will work cross platform?

Yes.

> Does AtomicU64 always undergo operations as big endian ?

No.

> Or does it sometime under go operations as little endian ?

Yes. Well, "sometime" - endianess is fixed to a platform.

> how should I change my code to work on any platform that AtomicU64 works on ?

No changes need to be done.

Operators `<<` `&` `!` represent **mathematical** operations, independent of how are they implemented or stored, the result is *mathematically* the same everywhere. `3 << 62` is equal to `3 * 2**64 = 13835058055282163712` everywhere, no matter how the number is represented.

Comment: Note that some platforms (e.g., 32-bit PowerPC and MIPS) lack 64-bit atomics, so `AtomicU64` will not work at all there.